# Screen recording goes black

Tags: display, screen-recorder

I am in the developer preview of Windows 11 Insider Preview 25290.1000 (rs_prerelease), and I had an issue while recording my screen using a cracked version of the Ispring suite recorder. So, I recorded my screen and my video and did my work. I then went back and checked the playback, only to find a black screen appearing randomly, lasting up to 10 minutes, but with the cursor moving around just fine. It seemed odd as it was the first time I had seen such a thing. Is it normal for the dev preview to break down like this often? Please let me know if anyone else got the same error and what I can do to resolve it potentially.

Comment: If its a preview (pre-release), then your should expect some bugs ?? !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that I faced the same issue in the developer preview of Windows 11 Insider Preview 25290.1000 (rs_prerelease) as well. I had a similar experience while recording my screen in a team call, and encountered a black screen with the cursor moving around fine. This issue is not uncommon in the developer preview version of Windows 11, and several users have reported similar problems with the screen going black randomly while recording or sharing their screen.

After conducting extensive research and troubleshooting, it appears that the issue is a bug in the current version of the developer preview, and it can only be resolved by waiting for a new update to be released by Microsoft. Unfortunately, there is no immediate solution to fix the issue at the moment, and we just have to wait for Microsoft to address it in a future update.

In the meantime, you can try recording your screen in other applications or third-party software, and check if the issue persists. If you encounter the same issue, it's likely to be related to the Windows 11 developer preview version and not specific to any application that you are using. I hope this helps, and let me know if you have any further questions or concerns.

Edit 1: So I updated to Windows 11 Insider Preview 25295.1000 (rs_prerelease) and the problem seems to be resolved in this update. Hope that it works for you too! If it still does not, you might need to take your device to a repair center and ask them.

Comment: Thanks @Suresh Metha, It seems to work fine for me after the update too. weird that the update had such a peculiar problem.